# Highlighted file names

Tags: desktop, filenames

I did something to my desktop (dragged a picture from a word document on the desktop, a window popped up saying something like "live desktop" or "active desktop", not sure) and now all the filenames look like that, whatever wallpaper I put:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please *always* include your OS. Solutions very often depend on the Operating System being used. Are you using Unix, Linux, BSD, OSX, something else? Which version?

Comment: which windows version ?

Comment: Seems like Vista or XP...

Comment: Looks like you set the icon background to white instead of transparent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this might help:

Right click

"My Computer" > Properties > "Advance" tab > "Settings" button in the "Performance" section >

Scroll to the bottom and *check* "**Use drop shadows for icon labels on the desktop**".

Source :  [ [::: link :::](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/265052-45-remove-highlight-desktop-icons#8775399) ]